# Google Analytics ecommerce does not fire from local file

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to set ecommerce tag firing from the local file. At the moment I am using hardcoded data. 
The GA file itself is working and sending page view. However, the bit with ecommerce doesn't work. No information in the console, no errors like it doesn't exist.

The code is below:

```html
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-17316967-1', 'auto');
ga('set', 'checkProtocolTask', null); // Disable file protocol checking.
ga('set', 'checkStorageTask', null); // Disable cookie storage checking.
ga('set', 'historyImportTask', null); // Disable history checking (requires reading from cookies).
ga('send', 'pageview');


</script>

<script>
  ga('require', 'ecommerce'); 
  ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    'id'            : '298',
    'affiliation'   : 'Tax',
    'revenue'       : '0.0',
    'shipping'      : '0.0',
    'tax'           : '0.0'
  });
  ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    'id'      : '227',
    'sku'     : '227',
    'name'    : 'Alpha 0 featured listing',
    'category': 'Appliances',
    'price'   : '23.34',
    'quantity': 1
  });
  ga('ecommerce:send');

</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried with the debugger extension? 
Chrome extension here 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/analytics%20debugger?hl=en
Your code looks fine.